# mount ignores user option at drvfs mount point

Tags: mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

In WSL2 I've configured in `/etc/fstab` a `drvfs` mount point to be mountable by an ordinary (non-root) user:

```
F:                      /mnt/f          drvfs           rw,noatime,dirsync,noauto,exec,umask=0022,user  0 0
```

Despite the `user` mount option applied `mount` still requires superuser privileges:

```bash
$ mount /mnt/f/
mount: /mnt/f: must be superuser to use mount.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
<3>WSL (839) ERROR: UtilCreateProcessAndWait:687: /bin/mount failed with status 0x2000
```

Why does `mount` ignore `user` mount option? And how to allow ordinary users to mount `drvfs` without root?

Comment: Did you try this command : `mount F:` ? - Another question, are you sure the user has right on `/mnt/f` directory ?

Comment: @hidigoudi `mount F:` fails with the same error. I tried to change user, group and permissions on `/mnt/f/` but it didn't help.